# How to use texture-based spritefonts with incomplete character-set in XNA?

Tags: fonts, xna, textures, xna-4.0

I have created a texture-based font using the software SpriteFont 2.0.1. It works great if I use a default range of characters (numbers, capital/non-capital letters, etc.). However, now I want to create a spritefont only containing 0-9 and A-Z (only capital letters). I exported the texture can be found at:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55996726/LuckiestGuy.png

the *.spritefont file used in XNA is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<XnaContent xmlns:Graphics="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics">
  <Asset Type="Graphics:FontDescription">

  <!--
    Spacing is a float value, measured in pixels. Modify this value to change
    the amount of spacing in between characters.
    -->
<Spacing>0</Spacing>

<!--
    UseKerning controls the layout of the font. If this value is true, kerning information
    will be used when placing characters.
    -->
<UseKerning>true</UseKerning>

<fontMetrics file="LuckiestGuy.png">

  <character key="48">
    <x>1</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>53</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="49">
    <x>55</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>39</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="50">
    <x>95</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>46</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="51">
    <x>142</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>47</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="52">
    <x>190</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>48</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="53">
    <x>239</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>48</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="54">
    <x>288</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>49</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="55">
    <x>338</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>46</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="56">
    <x>385</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>49</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="57">
    <x>435</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>49</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="65">
    <x>485</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>56</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="66">
    <x>542</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>51</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="67">
    <x>594</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>47</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="68">
    <x>642</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>50</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="69">
    <x>693</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>45</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="70">
    <x>739</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>45</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="71">
    <x>785</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>53</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="72">
    <x>839</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>52</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="73">
    <x>892</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>33</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="74">
    <x>926</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>47</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="75">
    <x>974</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>54</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="76">
    <x>1029</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>43</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="77">
    <x>1073</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>62</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="78">
    <x>1136</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>57</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="79">
    <x>1194</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>54</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="80">
    <x>1249</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>51</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="81">
    <x>1301</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>57</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="82">
    <x>1359</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>51</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="83">
    <x>1411</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>48</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="84">
    <x>1460</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>49</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="85">
    <x>1510</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>52</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="86">
    <x>1563</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>56</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="87">
    <x>1620</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>71</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="88">
    <x>1692</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>55</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="89">
    <x>1748</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>56</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
  <character key="90">
    <x>1805</x>
    <y>1</y>
    <width>45</width>
    <height>67</height>
  </character>
</fontMetrics>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

However, XNA gives me an error saying "The character 'E' (0x0045) is not available in this spritefont." when I want to render a word starting with 'E'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alright, I found out the the spriteFont XML description is not even used in XNA for texture-based fonts.